# Assemble-time read the value of a data variable

Tags: assembly, nasm, osdev

I am making a sort of test operating system, as a proof of concept. I am using NASM as my assembler, and am wondering if I can multiply a constant (ie. 512) by a variable (ie. `SECTOR_COUNT`).

In case it helps, the actual command that I use to compile the boot loader is as follows:

```sh
nasm -f bin boot.asm -o os.bin
```

an example of what I want to do is as follows:

```
begin_main_program:

times (512*[SECTOR_COUNT]-511)-($-begin_main_program)
```

when I try to compile that, NASM says that I need to pass in a constant value. So, I'm wondering if there is a way to do the above, and not have to pass in a constant.

EDIT: fixed `times (512*SECTOR_COUNT-511)...` to be `times (512*[SECTOR_COUNT]-511)...` (a de referenced pointer i guess)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  When the assembler runs, the program does not yet exist so there is no memory to dereference.  The assembler does not support this sort of thing in any way.

Comment: Ok. I was just wondering if there was a way to use variables or even compile time macros (which also don't work with the times operator) and create padding to allow the bootloader to run without having to manually change the amount of sectors in both the Al register when calling interrupt 13h when reading the disk, and also having to change the padding of the other sectors when calculating the amount to zeros to add. Its a bit of a shame that you can't do that, however it's only a minor inconvenence, and I thought that kowing about this could be helpful in the future. thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use anything that is known to be a constant at this time.  E.g. you can do `SECTOR_COUNT EQU 5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how assembly language works.  It assembles bytes into the output file, and there's no way to read back those bytes at assemble time.  "Variable" is a high-level concept which you can *implement* in asm, but isn't natively supported<sup>1</sup>.

If you want to have multiple things depend on the same value,
**use `foo equ 123` to define an assemble-time constant you can use later in multiple places.**

To assemble some bytes in data memory with that value, use `bar: dw foo`.

It's an assemble-time constant so you *can* do things like `resb foo*512` or
`times (512*foo-511)-($-begin_main_program)`

If you only did `bar: dw 123`, there'd be no way to get at the `123` while assembling other lines.  (The `bar:` label is separate from the `dw 123` or `db 123, 0` or whatever you choose to put before or after it.  It gives you a way to refer to that address from elsewhere, e.g. `dw bar` to assemble a pointer, or `mov ax, [bar]` to assemble an instruction that at run-time will load from that absolute address.)

---

Footnote 1: Except in NASM's macro language, with stuff like `%assign i i+1` - useful inside a `%rep 10` / `%endrep` block.
https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.1.8

Comment: I'm not sure why when I tried this before it didn't work... Anyway thanks!