# How to reference the value of data section in macro?

Tags: assembly, x86, att, gnu-assembler

I don't know how to reference it, if I use macro, and the parameter seems to a string, and if I use addressing mode on it, then macro get the string yet, like `(test), $test`, .etc.

Below code just for example!!

```
.macro newcat str
newcat:
    .string "\str"
.equ newcat_len, .-newcat
.endm

.section .data
test:
    .string "abc"

# expect newcat has string "abc", but it got string "test"
newcat test

.section .text

.globl _start

_start:
    movq $1, %rax
    movq $1, %rdi
    movq $newcat, %rsi
    movq $newcat_len, %rdx
    syscall
    
    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```

Comment: Why would you expect to see "abc" without using the `test:` label in the syscall below?

Comment: @ErikEidt above code just for example, It' s meaningless! I saw similar useage of NASM, so I tried to through pass parameter to create many other macro in my other code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read memory contents at assemble time, with or without macros.  You can't assemble bytes into some section and then have another directive copy those bytes somewhere else.

**What you can do is define a new symbol to have the *same address* as another symbol**, which is obviously more efficient for read-only data (`.section .rodata`).  You'd only want to actually duplicate the ASCII bytes as initializers for mutable `.data`, or in some rare case if you needed unique addresses for two things even though the data happened to be the same.  (Perhaps as LUT entries for a `struct { int i; char s[4];} table[16];` or something.)

```
.section .rodata
str1:
str2:            # you can have 2 labels that happen to have the same address
    .asciz "Hello"

# at any point later
 .set str3, str1     # an alias, just like if you'd put str3: before/after str2:
```

Hopefully this example also makes it clearer that labels only happen to be followed by data, they aren't like C variables where it's the one and only way to reference that location.

---

**If you want the same string data twice** without having it appear again literally in your file, the string itself needs to be a macro.  And you need to reference that macro name, not some label that happens to be followed by some pseudo-instructions that emit some data there.

```
.macro foo
 .asciz "the text"
.endm

.data
str1: foo
str2: foo
```

If you want, you could have the macro take a symbol name as a parameter and include those labels, and even define a `.equ` with another name derived from that if you want.

---

Or with the C preprocessor (name the file `foo.S` and build with `gcc -c` instead of plain `as`).  I'm not sure if GAS's own macro language allows macros like this that expand to a single token, not a whole line.  I find it cumbersome compared to NASM.

```
#define foo  "the text"

.data
str1: .asciz foo
str2: .asciz foo
```

---

Other assemblers work the same way, for example NASM: [Assemble-time read the value of a data variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70314352/assemble-time-read-the-value-of-a-data-variable)

Comment: @OnlyWick: It seems only distantly related to the title question about macros.  Ask it separately, with more details about what you did and what you're seeing.  (`*ABS*` is I think for raw values without an associated section; most symbol values are addresses in a section, but `.equ a, 10` or the equivalent `.set a, 10` just set an absolute numeric value, not relative to the start of any section.  But I'm not super clear on all the details of how that works.)

Comment: On ELF targets you can also use a special section with the “merge strings” attribute to have the linker take care of this.  Not sure though if NASM supports it.

Comment: @fuz: Oh, to collapse duplicate read-only data down to one copy with all the labels having that address?  This question seemed to want the opposite thing, perhaps as initializers for mutable `.data`.  Weird to do that with strings, which I maybe should have mentioned.  It's possible some beginners didn't know you could `.set str2, str1` to make it an alias.

Comment: I'm actually not really sure what the question is asking for, really.

Comment: @fuz What is the `merge string`? To be honest, sometimes I don't understand what you said, and I need to google...

Comment: @fuz Just for using the value of data/bss section in macro..

Comment: @OnlyWick: Updated my answer with a suggestion based on a possible X-Y problem: usually you don't want to duplicate the same string multiple times, except for mutable `.data` initializers.  But most strings are `.rodata`.

Comment: @OnlyWick It's an optimisation where the linker can deduplicate strings.  If the same string appears multiple times in the program, the linker can merge all copies so the string is stored only once.