# Calculate checksum in pre-processor with NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, preprocessor

For example, I have an assembly program written in NASM, and the output is raw binary. 
I want to append an additional byte at the end, indicating the checksum of the file. 
I know NASM has the `%rep` directive. I think I can traverse every byte with it. But I am not sure how to reference an anticipated byte of the raw binary.

Comment: There is no way to do that with NASM. I think FASM does have a way to do this.

Comment: KISS: Write a program that reads the raw binary output, computes the checksum, and appends the result to the file. I would claim that such a program already exists.

Comment: NASM has no way to read back bytes that it's emitted into the output.  That's why for data, you have to use an assemble-time constant for stuff like [How to reference the value of data section in macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72851856) (GAS has the same limitation.)  Totally agreed with Kai: appending some bytes to the file is very easy to do separately, you don't even need to define an offset for another tool to overwrite.